# In F# how do you get the parameters for a function?

Tags: reflection, f#

Given a list of functions, how do you extract a list containing the type of the first parameter for each function in the list?

The list is defined as:

```
let messageHandlers = [
    fun (message: MessageA) -> (), // Cast
    fun (message: MessageB) -> () // Cast
]
```

The list of types could then be defined as:

```
let getFirstParam x = x.GetType().UseReflectionToGetTheParameters

let types = List.map getFirstParam messageHandlers
```

I would have expected a list called `Parameters` or something similar on the `FSharpFunc` however I can't find one.

Comment: As so often, the real question here is probably what the "higher" goal is that you want to achieve. Depending on that, this detail may or may not be necessary. And as @JohnPalmer said, the types will all be the same, as a `List` will only allow elements of the same type (in this case, functions with the same signature).

Comment: Think of it as pattern matching but I want to return the list of types in the match so I can iterate over them. The application is a simple message bus.

Comment: Couldn't the different message be part of an union and then have a list of `Message -> unit` (or Response instead of unit, Response being another union of the possible response) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about getting the types statically instead, to avoid the risk of error, like this:

```
let messageHandlers, types =
    let withArgType (f: 'T -> unit) = (f :> obj, typeof<'T>)
    [
        withArgType (fun (param1: MessageA) -> ())
        withArgType (fun (param1: MessageB) -> ())
    ]
    |> List.unzip
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, a list can't contain elements of different types. Therefore, all the functions in your `methods` list will have the exact same first parameter.

But ok, you can technically get around that by erasing the type of the functions (i.e. casting them to `obj`):

```
let methods = [
   (fun (param1: MyRecordType) -> ()) :> obj
   (fun (param1: AnotherType) -> ()) :> obj
]
```

Now you've got yourself a nice `obj list`, in which every element is actually a function. Except that's not known at compile time, because you've casted them to `obj`.

Now, functions in F# are represented by the class `FSharpFunc<_,_>`. The first generic parameter is input, the second - output. So you can just take the first generic argument, and that's your answer:

```
let paramType = fn.GetType().GetGenericArguments().[0]
```

Except I would also put a safeguard in place to make sure that the `obj` I'm passed is actually a function:

```
let funcType = typeof<FSharpFunc<_,_>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition()

let getFunctionParamType fn =
   let fnType = fn.GetType()
   if fnType.IsGenericType && 
      funcType.IsAssignableFrom (fnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
   then
      Some (fnType.GetGenericArguments().[0])
   else
      None
```

**NOTE:** it is necessary to use `funcType.IsAssignableFrom` (as opposed to just comparing with `funcType =`), because some functions could be implemented as a custom class that's *derived* from `FSharpFunc<_,_>`.

**Update**: as **kvb** points out in the comments, for a more solid solution, one may use `FSharpType.GetFunctionElements` and `FSharpType.IsFunction` functions, which essentially wrap the above logic in a more convenient, F#-friendly way:

```
let getFunctionParamType fn =
   if FSharpType.IsFunction fn && 
      let input, output = FSharpType.GetFunctionElements fn
      Some input
   else
      None
```

**Beware** though: reflection is a tricky thing, easy to get wrong and prone to silent failures. Judging by your question, you don't really understand how it all works, which would be a strong contraindication for using it. Perhaps if you described your overarching problem, someone would be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: I've added a little more context, but I wanted to keep the question general so it was more useful to others

Comment: If you're using raw .NET reflection then checking types using equality is usually wrong - you should be using IsAssignableFrom instead (the function's runtime type could be any concrete type derived from `_ -> _` and that would be fine).  However, in this case you don't need to use .NET reflection directly - use  `FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.GetFunctionElements` (guarded by `FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsFunction` if you desire).

Comment: Additionally, your definition of `funcType` doesn't even compile - you're calling `GetGenericMethodDefinition` on a type rather than a method.  You should use `let funcType = typedefof<_->_>` instead.

Comment: Thank you @kvb for pointing out the mistakes. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - Since you're still not using IsAssignableFrom, your initial definition hasn't really been fixed: `getFunctionParamType (fun x -> x + 1)` returns `None`.

Comment: @kvb: well, I meant to leave it incorrect and then explain why it's incorrect in the last paragraph... But ok, I've modified that part as well.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Tarmil's great answer I ended up getting the types statically but I also wrapped each function in a more general function.

```
let messageHandlers, types =
    let withArgType (f: 'T -> unit) = 
        let genericFunc = fun (o: obj) -> (f (o :?> 'T))
        (genericFunc, typeof<'T>)
    [
        withArgType (fun (message: MessageA) -> ())
        withArgType (fun (message: MessageB) -> ())
    ]
    |> List.unzip
```